# SQL Stored Procedures Editing

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, t-sql

I´m developing a database about the orders for my network with SQL and Visual Basic but I don´t see the results that i want, in visual basic I received an error this is my stored procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE modificar 
     @NumeroIP nvarchar(255), 
     @Usuario nvarchar(255),
     @DirecciónMAC nvarchar(255), 
     @MACRestricciones nvarchar(255), 
     @MACSinRestricciones nvarchar(255), 
     @Enmascarada nvarchar(255), 
     @SistemaOperativo nvarchar(255), 
     @DirecciónArea nvarchar(255), 
     @TipoEquipo nvarchar(255),
     @Observación nvarchar(255)
AS
    UPDATE dbo.IP
    SET Usuario = @Usuario, 
        DirecciónMAC = @DirecciónMAC, 
        MACRestricciones = @MACRestricciones, 
        MACSinRestricciones = @MACSinRestricciones, 
        Enmascarada = @Enmascarada,
        SistemaOperativo = @SistemaOperativo,
        DirecciónArea = @DirecciónArea, 
        TipoEquipo = @TipoEquipo,
        Observación = @Observación
    WHERE
        NumeroIP = @NumeroIP

    RAISERROR ('Valor modificado', 16, 1)
```

And my VB.NET is:

```
Dim conex As New SqlConnection("Data Source=GABRIELA;Initial Catalog=IPS_Database;Integrated Security=True")

Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("editar", conex)
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

conex.Open()

Dim para As New SqlParameter("@NumeroIP", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
para.Size = 255
para.Value = TextBoxDireccionIP.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add(para)

Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
da.SelectCommand = cmd
da.SelectCommand.Connection = conex

Dim ds As New DataSet
da.Fill(ds, "IPS_DatabaseDataSet1")

DataGridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables("TablaIPS")

NumeroIPPTextBox.Clear()
UsuarioTextBox.Clear()
DireccionMACTextBox.Clear()
DireccionAreaTextBox.Clear()
ObservacionTextBox.Clear()
DireccionAreaTextBox.Clear()
ObservacionTextBox.Clear()

conex.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Could you help me to run it?

Comment: Are you commiting the transaction?

Comment: You can use `RAISERROR ('Valor modificado', 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT`

Answer (score 3):

You will always receive an error in VB because with the `RAISEERROR` statement at the end of your procedure you are always returning an error.

From [**the documentation**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx):

> The message is returned as a server error message to the calling
>   application or to an associated CATCH block of a TRY…CATCH construct.

You should consider switching to using `PRINT` instead of `RAISERROR` in your procedure.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have written your stored procedure it will always Raise an error.

Also please read this [`TSQL Try / Catch within Transaction or vice versa?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23056973/tsql-try-catch-within-transaction-or-vice-versa/23057666#23057666), I explained in great detail how the `TRY..CATCH` block works and how you can appropriately do the error handling with it.

Your SP should be written like this...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE modificar 
  @NumeroIP nvarchar(255)
, @Usuario nvarchar(255)
, @DirecciónMAC nvarchar(255)
, @MACRestricciones nvarchar(255)
, @MACSinRestricciones nvarchar(255)
, @Enmascarada nvarchar(255)
, @SistemaOperativo nvarchar(255)
, @DirecciónArea nvarchar(255)
, @TipoEquipo nvarchar(255)
, @Observación nvarchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

 BEGIN TRY 
   BEGIN TRANSACTION; 
     update dbo.IP
       set  Usuario = @Usuario
          , DirecciónMAC = @DirecciónMAC
          , MACRestricciones = @MACRestricciones
          , MACSinRestricciones = @MACSinRestricciones
          , Enmascarada = @Enmascarada
          , SistemaOperativo = @SistemaOperativo
          , DirecciónArea = @DirecciónArea
          , TipoEquipo = @TipoEquipo
          , Observación = @Observación
    where NumeroIP = @NumeroIP
   COMMIT TRANSACTION;
 END TRY 

 BEGIN CATCH

  IF (@@TRANCOUNT <> 0)
   BEGIN
     ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
   END

   raiserror ('Valor modificado',16,1)
 END CATCH 
END
```