# SQL Server transaction not committing

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions, commit

I have a SQL Server transaction which adds a column to a table, and then it adds some value to that column. It runs perfectly, but it doesn't commit the changes.

I checked with `@@trancount`, and it's value is 1 after running the query.

What is wrong with the transaction?

Thanks!

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    ALTER TABLE Table
        ADD ColumnName VARCHAR(200) NULL;
    GO

    BEGIN TRY
        UPDATE ColumnName 
        SET ColumnName = 'some value'

        COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END CATCH;
```

Comment: why used `GO` inside `BEGIN` ... `END`

Comment: Which dbms are you using? That code is product specific.

Comment: replace table name with column name

Comment: I'm using MS SQL, without Go, the newly added column is not recognized.

Comment: "It runs perfectly, but it doesn't work"? I would say it doesn't run perfectly then... You need a table in the update statement.

Comment: I think the `begin transaction` should be _after_ the `GO`

Comment: Sorry, i mistyped the update statement, the table name is there:
UPDATE Table SET ColumnName = 'some value'

Comment: @PeterAbolins it does what I want, I just need to run Commit after the query.

Comment: if `@@trancount == 1` after running the script, then nothing was committed. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trancount-transact-sql

Comment: Yes, that's the question, why it doesn't commit automatically.?

Comment: Transactions apply to [DML](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848766(v=sql.110).aspx), not [DDL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/statements).

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your `update` to tell it which table to update.

```
 UPDATE Table SET ColumnName = 'some value'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do it this way, it will work. `XACT_ABORT` will automatically rollback the transaction if an error occurs at runtime. I have had problems with using `TRY...CATCH` in the past, and in this case, it doesn't seem warranted.

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    ALTER TABLE Table
        ADD ColumnName VARCHAR(200) NULL;

    UPDATE Table 
        SET ColumnName = 'some value';

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;

SET XACT_ABORT OFF
```

**UPDATE**

I found this, which explains the process better, if you still want to use the `TRY...CATCH` construct.

[Try...Catch inside Transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23056973/tsql-try-catch-within-transaction-or-vice-versa)