# INSERT to parent-child with @@IDENTITY

Tags: sql-server, parent-child, identity

I've read related other questions but could not find a direct answer so I hoped to confirm that the best (only?) way in T-SQL to INSERT into a parent and many to  many child is via two separate statements as at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/00180/3

Note that in my actual case the params include a TVP for the child table and the INSERTS are within a stored procedure with a TRY -- CATCH block.  Regarding the latter (and [TSQL Try / Catch within Transaction or vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23056973/tsql-try-catch-within-transaction-or-vice-versa)) is a COMMIT/ROLLBACK useful or too much overhead for something simple like this?

Comment: If you are starting with multi row TVP then I usually loop my TVP with cursors and then insert using SCOPE_IDENTITY after each insert into table Interests and then take the value of SCOPE_IDENTIY and use that to insert into Interest2Currencies.  Please understand SCOPE_IDENTITY if you do not understand it already.

Comment: Thanks @SqlSurfer I was not aware of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920558/what-is-the-difference-between-scope-identity-identity-identity-and-ide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't necessarily have to use a cursor, but you will have to manage the `identity` fields in some fashion.  If you're trying to create both a parent and children records, then you'd need to do an `insert` into the parent, grab `scope_identity`, and feed that `scope_identity` into the children records.

If you're trying to insert multiple parent records *and* multiple children records, you've got a bit more complex scenario, which needs some additional description in your question.  It's possible to do - you'd need to have `identity_insert on` if you wanted to do multi-row inserts into that parent table, and you'd be managing your `identity` columns explicitly (i.e., in your own statements, rather than relying on the `identity` property to create them for you).  It can be done, and there are scenarios where it's more than appropriate (cursors are still miserable performers in mssql).

Give us more of a detailed question (with the code in the question, please - the code out there is pretty basic and really should be inlined here) and let's see what you're really asking.

Comment: Thanks fot the information, I'm not actually inserting multiple parents so no need for additional detail (until I cross that bridge :) but your insight was definitely helpful with my concern.