# How to get the custom error of a stored procedure which is executed inside a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am currently studying how to handle exceptions from a nested stored procedure in an SQL server.

Unfortunately, a scenario came across where I want to output the custom error on a stored procedure[2] which is executed inside a stored procedure[1].

Here is an example:

```
/*
    create the master-table
*/
CREATE TABLE master_table
(
    pk_id INT IDENTITY(5,5),
    access_num INT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    first_name NVARCHAR(MAX)
    PRIMARY KEY (pk_id)
)
GO

/*
    create the child-table
*/
CREATE TABLE child_table
(
    pk_id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    val INT UNIQUE,
    msgs NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (pk_id)
)
GO


/*
    create the master procedure
*/
CREATE or ALTER PROC uspInsertIntoMaster
    @AccessNum INT,
    @FirstName NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Message NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS WITH NO_INFOMSGS;
    SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRAN
            INSERT INTO master_table (access_num, first_name)
            VALUES (@AccessNum, @FirstName)

            EXEC uspInsertIntoChild 4, @Message;

        IF (@@TRANCOUNT = 1)
            COMMIT
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK;

        THROW;

        IF (XACT_STATE()) = -1
                BEGIN
                    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
                END;

        IF (XACT_STATE()) = 1
            BEGIN
                COMMIT TRANSACTION;
            END;
    END CATCH
END
GO


/*
    create the child procedure
*/
CREATE or ALTER PROC uspInsertIntoChild
    @Value INT,
    @Message NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(2048);
BEGIN
    DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS WITH NO_INFOMSGS;
    SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRY
        IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM child_table WHERE val = @Value)
            BEGIN
                SET @ErrorMessage = FORMATMESSAGE(50010, @Value);
                THROW 50010, @ErrorMessage, 1;
            END;

        ELSE
            BEGIN TRAN 
                INSERT INTO child_table (val, msgs) VALUES (@Value, @Message)

            IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
                COMMIT
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK;

        THROW;

        IF (XACT_STATE()) = -1
                BEGIN
                    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
                END;

        IF (XACT_STATE()) = 1
            BEGIN
                COMMIT TRANSACTION;
            END;
    END CATCH
END
GO
```

---

**Custom ERROR Message**

```
EXEC sys.sp_addmessage 
    @msgnum = 50010, 
    @severity = 16, 
    @msgtext = N'Invalid Input. Error occurred at procedure uspInsertIntoChild',
    @lang = 'us_english';   
GO
```

If I try to execute the below code. I expect it to fail on the second execution and throw the custom error above.

```
EXEC uspInsertIntoMaster 4, N'miKeL', N'Get Well Soon'
EXEC uspInsertIntoMaster 5, N'miKeL', N'Get Well Soon'
```

But unfortunately, instead of having the custom error I've got

> Msg 50010, Level 16, State 1, Procedure uspInsertIntoChild, Line 14
> [Batch Start Line 105] Error: 50010, Severity: 16, State: 1.
> (Params:).  The error is printed in terse mode because there was error
> during formatting. Tracing, ETW, notifications etc are skipped.

---

### EDIT (@Charlieface)

First, I removed the `TRY/CATCH` block from `master proc` first and then both, yet still the same error occur. I also removed the `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS WITH NO_INFOMSGS` as @M.Ali suggest.

**new `Master Proc`**

```
CREATE or ALTER PROC uspInsertIntoMaster
    @AccessNum INT,
    @FirstName NVARCHAR(30),
    @Message NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON;
    
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        INSERT INTO master_table (access_num, first_name)
        VALUES (@AccessNum, @FirstName)

        EXEC uspInsertIntoChild 4, @Message;

    IF (@@TRANCOUNT = 1)
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
GO
```

**new `Child Proc`**

```
CREATE or ALTER PROC uspInsertIntoChild
    @Value INT,
    @Message NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(MAX);
BEGIN
    
    SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON;
    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM child_table WHERE val = @Value)
        BEGIN
            SET @ErrorMessage = FORMATMESSAGE(50010, @Value);
            -- I want to thow
            THROW 50010, @ErrorMessage, 1;
        END;

    ELSE
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
            INSERT INTO child_table (val, msgs) VALUES (@Value, @Message)

        IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
            COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
GO
```

## EDIT 2

Silly me. I edited the formatted messages. But never thought of editing also the Control Character `%s` which indicates for string character. I tried to pass an integer parameter to the error message, so it should be `%i`.

**final `FORMATTED` Error Message**

```
EXEC sys.sp_addmessage 
    @msgnum = 50010, 
    @severity = 16, 
    @msgtext =
    N'Invalid Input %i. Error occured at procedure uspInsertIntoChild', /*Mobile number [%s] is invalid. Input a valid number*/
    @lang = 'us_english';   
GO
```

Comment: Why not use [`THROW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to throw your custom error message? The documentation comes with plenty of [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#a-using-throw-to-raise-an-exception) to show you how to do this.

Comment: :O Just out of interest, why do you have `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS WITH NO_INFOMSGS;` in your proc definition? I hope you understand the implications of this command and aware of the harm it can cause to your application and server speed.

Comment: Also, error messages can't be 1 billion characters in length, they are capped at 2048 characters.

Comment: You have your commit transaction in `Catch Block` it should be in the `Try Block` take a look at this answer and it will help you to understand the correct use of try and catch block along with raiserror/throw function [`TSQL Try / Catch within Transaction or vice versa?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23056973/tsql-try-catch-within-transaction-or-vice-versa/23057666#23057666)

Comment: `first_name NVARCHAR(MAX)`. Really ? Whose first name is even that long

Comment: @Larnu 1st comment. I tried using throw, it is in the child procedure. And I want that custom error to be thrown when I execute it. Yet, because I'm executing it inside a stored procedure, I can't get that custom error. 2nd comment. Thank you for that.

Comment: @Squirrel, this is just an example. In my main db. I maximize it to only 30 :)

Comment: @M.Ali, thought this has to do with the performance of the stored procedure.

Comment: It's trying to format the value into `Invalid Input. Error occurred at procedure uspInsertIntoChild` but there is no equivalent `%s` to format it into. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The message you are using does not have any formatting paramters, so `FORMATMESSAGE` is throwing an error.**

You need something like this:

```sql
EXEC sys.sp_addmessage 
    @msgnum = 50010, 
    @severity = 16, 
    @msgtext = N'Invalid Input %s. Error occurred at procedure uspInsertIntoChild',
    @lang = 'us_english';
```

---

**By the way, if you use `XACT_ABORT ON` then it is not necessary to catch and rollback.** It is only necessary if you are using custom logging, which in this case you are not.

Futhermore, the code you have currently doesn't work for other reasons:

- In the `CATCH` you would want to `ROLLBACK` never `COMMIT` usually.
- If `XACT_STATE = -1` then the `ROLLBACK` will fail
- No code is executed after `THROW;` anyway.

**So I would say remove the whole `TRY/CATCH`, keep `XACT_ABORT ON` and log messages as you have done using `sp_addmessage`**